# How to disable TinyMCE automatic text replacement

Tags: tinymce

I use tinyMCE version 5.07 I noticed that when I insert the text `#1` it automatically changes to `<h1>1</h1>`

How can I disable this automatic formatting or change it that `#` will not trigger automatic formatting?

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is a very old question, however, I thought this might help.
in the initialization of the editor, textpatters can be disabled

```
text_patterns: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have the `textpattern` plugin enabled:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/textpattern/

The `#` character when running that plugin turns the remainder of the line into an `<h1>` tag.  If you don't run that plugin that will stop happening.