# How to disable TinyMCE automatic text replacement in version 6

Tags: tinymce-6

This question has already been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181517/how-to-disable-tinymce-automatic-text-replacement), but the answer - the textpattern plugin - applied to version 5. I am now using version 6 with no plugins active, but still the editor replaces text between asterisks as italic. How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in the textpattern plugin was moved into the core editor in TinyMCE 6.  This is covered in the [Migrating from TinyMCE 5](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/migration-from-5x/) documentation page.

If you want no text patterns at all you need to set the `text_patterns` configuration option to `false`:

```
text_patterns: false
```

as documented here https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/content-behavior-options/#text_patterns.